# c# await Task.Run dialog box hidden behind my WPF app main form

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a WPF `Saraff.Twain` scanning application. To chose the data source I have:

```
private async void selectButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.EnabledIO = false; //disable some controls
        await Task.Run(() => this._twain32.SelectSource());
    } ...
}
```

`twain32.SelectSource` displays a dialog box for selecting a data source, but the dialog box appears behind the main form.

It also happens when it try to get an image from a data source:

```
private async void acquireButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
    {
        this.EnabledIO = false; //disable some controls
        await Task.Run(() => this._twain32.Acquire());

        _twain32.CloseDSM();
    } ...
}
```

Is there a way to bring in the dialogue boxes to the front? I tried to
minimize and then maximize the main form but if there is another app running, it will show behind those anyway. It is very confusing for the user because it seems that the application is stuck, even though the taskbar shows that there is another window waiting for an input.

Thanks a lot, and please forgive my posting lack of experience in here.

Comment: What happens to the form when you don't use Task.Run? Also behind the main form?

Comment: I havet tried ... I think Task.Run is necessary according Saraff.Twain samples, I guess. 

I mean "Behind" to the mainform or window staying at front... I have to move it in order to see the dialogs boxes

Comment: Try it and see. The reason why it is necessary is because it will block your UI thread and make it unresponsive but that's OK because you need to figure out if it is background thread causing the issue or not.

Comment: This might be hard to solve without being able to see the code for the `_twain32` methods.

Comment: The normal way to handle this would be to give the new dialog a handle to the parent window that created the dialog. In some cases this is done automatically by picking the root window for the thread, but that would require the code to be run on the UI thread. If neither is possible it seem like a problem with the library, so you might want to contact the provider for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method without a reason. It is only useful when you want to do background work without blocking the UI. The background work should have no interaction with the UI. In your case it is obvious that the `_twain32.SelectSource` method contains UI related code, so you should call it directly:

```
private async void selectButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.EnabledIO = false; //disable some controls
        this._twain32.SelectSource();
    }
}
```

In case this makes the UI of your application non-responsive, then you are both in trouble. You because you'll (probably) have to search for a better library, and the library creators because they'll (probably) lose a customer.

Comment: indeed it was not necessary to use task.run as the dialog boxes work the same without it, but still have the problem and now the app is non-responsive, I guess you are rigth, it is a library issue Thanks. Will upvote @JohanP comment to as soon I find out how